# convert responsive page to pdf with acrobat button

Tags: pdf, browser, responsive-design, acrobat

Couldn't decide if this is a question better for Stack Overflow or Superuser, haven't got any bites on Superuser yet...

I have Adobe Acrobat 9.0 Pro, and with that, the Convert Web Page to PDF button that displays in IE. We use this at work to review web pages and comment/markup for changes, etc.

When I use it on a web page that is responsive (such as http://microsoft.com) the resulting PDF shows the page laid out as if the browser window was sized down, but then it stretches all the elements to fit the width of the PDF.

Does anyone know if this is because of the rendering engine the Convert button uses? The resulting PDF looks a bit similar to how the page would look in Quirks mode in IE9 (using F12 developer tools and choosing Quirks mode from the Document Mode drop down.) Thanks for any help!

Comment: I think that button just "prints" the html file into Adobe Acrobat Distiller (a virtual PDF printer) with the default page-size, so everything gets stretched to that page-size. If this is the case (I am not 100% sure), then it is the browser who does the rendering. By the way this question does belong to SU rather than SO since it is not related to programming.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Then perhaps there is a difference in how Adobe Acrobat Distiller prints and what would actually print if sent to a physical printer, because doing a print preview on microsoft.com does not quite show the same results that get put in the PDF. Maybe Distiller doesn't use the @media print stylesheets when printing?

Comment: Also, I wasn't sure if anyone on SU would know as much about rendering engines, and now we're getting into print styles. I see your point though, I have no code to show/fix.

Comment: There should not be any difference between printing to Distiller and printing into a real printer, and the Distiller does not know about stylesheets, that's IE job. You could try printing yourself from the print menu into distiller and compare the results just to narrow down the issue.